# cURL takes forever to do an FTP upload

Tags: bash, curl, upload, ftp, cygwin

I have written a longish deployment script in bash that I run under cygwin. If deploying to a remote server, the script will upload the resulting app to an FTP server using curl, like this:

```
if [ $where == "remote" ]
then
    for i in `find deploy/ -type f`; do
        curl.exe -u "***:***" -T $i "ftp://address.co.uk/public_html/java/desktop/$i"
    done
fi
```

The problem is sometimes curl just can't finish an upload and just sits there blocking the other downloads displaying

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:15:14 --:--:--     0
```

This particular file is ~2,5KB so it shouldnt take that long... I have to kill the script and start again... Until all of them upload correctly.

I tried adding `&` to run it in the background but I got a lot of `curl: (28) Timeout was reached` right where all the uploads start.

How can I fix my script to upload files without issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help guys, I went with [wput](http://wput.sourceforge.net/):

```
./wput/wput.exe -N deploy "ftp://****:****@address.co.uk/public_html/java/desktop/"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try these curl options to control it's behaviour.

`connect-timeout <secs>` to set the seconds before connection attempt fails.

`--speed-time` sets the number of seconds of slower transfer than `--speed_limit` bytes per second are allowed before curl aborts the transfer.

`--speed_limit`  sets the limit in bytes/sec below which curl will abort the transfer.

```
  curl --connect_timeout <seconds> --speed-time <secs> --speed_limit <speed in bytes/sec>
```

`-v` gives more info on the transfer which may help if you are trying to find out why transfers are so slow.

Comment: I fail to see how these would help me, aborting transfers is not an option here. I used `-v` and everything connects without problems but then some of the uploads stagnate

Comment: It may do. If a connection timed out for example the return code from curl could be checked. The script would need to be modified slightly to check the return code and repeat the curl command until successful. This would reduce the bothersome intervention during uploading.

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, FTP connections or all connections are rate limited on your destination server.

It would follow that the delays for some file uploads are due to the SYN packets being discarded.

I would suggest you run one FTP session and use that to upload recursively or introduce a delay between invocations of `curl`.

Ideally your destination server would support `rsync` over `ssh`: this would be bandwidth optimal.

---

**Update**
After a quick search, there's a command line program called [`lftp`](http://lftp.yar.ru/) that provides ftp mirroring functionality.

Adapted from a guide [here](http://sina.salek.ws/content/how-mirrorsync-remote-ftp-folder-local-folder), something like this should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST='address.co.uk'
USER='myuser'
PASS='mypass'
TARGETFOLDER='/public_html/java/desktop/'
SOURCEFOLDER='deploy/'

lftp -f "
open $HOST
user $USER $PASS
lcd $SOURCEFOLDER
mirror --reverse --delete --verbose $SOURCEFOLDER $TARGETFOLDER
bye
"
```

I'd suggest you'd do it without the `--delete` until you're sure you've got the arguments right!

Comment: I wish ssh was an option, I'm going to test using various delays and report back.

Comment: Using up to 30 seconds timeout did not fix the problem

Comment: Timeouts aren't going to help you, have you tried putting a "sleep 10" between `curl` invocations?